# How do I make a listbox sort items the same way as another listbox?

Tags: c#, listbox

I made it so that when I double-click the item in the listbox, it will be sent to another listbox. But the problem is that it's arranging it where there are large spaces in between every item added. How do I make it so that the 2nd listbox (toSell) sorts the same as the original listbox (applianceList)?

[Program design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ferjp.png)

```
        private void applianceList_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string appliances = Convert.ToString(applianceList.SelectedItem);
        toSell.Items.Add(appliances);
    }
```

[Example of how I want it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFw6X.png)

Comment: please share the code of both list boxes.

Comment: That's really it. It's just a code to transfer the items from "applianceList" to "toSell". There's no other code aside from that

Comment: it is strange that you are getting items in list in this order , horizontal and vertical with white space. there will be some change in properties of list box.

Comment: are you using any database servers or just a in-memory object?

Comment: There may be an error in your data. Did you check you did not create empty items? The only other thing I can think of is a difference in list settings. I recommend you to create a very simple demo application and see then if you get the same issue. You should post the code for this demo application. It is impossible to find out what is going wrong with only this small code fragment.